# Validate and filter URL parameters

Tags: php

If I use `$_GET['page'];` to get the value of the URL parameter page do I have to filter it before using it to check if the value is equal to ex "home" or is it safe to just check if it equals "home"?

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $page = 'home';
}

if($page === "home") {
   include_once('home.php');
} else {
  echo "error";
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should filter/validate all input. In your current code, you're barely using the input, but I'm betting it gets used more, and it's use may change. So sanitize it then you don't have to always consider if its a safe usage of the input

Comment: Ok. So filter_var($_GET['page'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); Should be enough then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page address looks like http://example.com/?page=hello, then
using `filter_var($_GET['page'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)` will not yield the result you are looking for. The value of `$_GET['page']` is just `hello`, not the whole URL. It won't make it through the URL filter.

When we say you have to validate the input, we mean the following. Consider you write your code like this:

```
include $_GET['post'] . '.php';
```

This seems pretty valid if the request is http://example.com/?page=hello, then `hello.php` is included. But what if I request http://example.com/?page=../db_config ? If you have a poorly secured DB config file which contains password in plain text, I'll be able to get it and do whatever I want with your database.

To filter out such cases you may want only to accept values which do not traverse file hierarchy. For example, like this:

```
// Word characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _.
// Non-word characters are dangerous for you!
// So if we detect any non-word character,
// we stop processing it immediately.
if (preg_match('~\W~', $_GET['page'])) {
    print 'Forbidden to hack my pretty files!';
    die;
}
```

After this check you are safe to include a filename constructed from user input.